# Sort an array in Ruby ignoring articles ("the", "a", "an")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I need to show a list of songs. Right now I'm doing this:

```
Song.all.sort {|x,y| x.artist.name <=> y.artist.name }
```

Unfortunately, this means that "The Notorious B.I.G" will sort with the T's while I want him to sort with the N's (i.e., I want to ignore articles -- "the", "a", and "an" -- for the purposes of sorting.

My first thought was to do this:

```
Song.all.sort {|x,y| x.artist.name.gsub(/^(the|a|an) /i, '') <=> y.artist.name.gsub(/^(the|a|an) /i, '') }
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?

Comment: I support adding an extra table-column, but if you want to do it this way, you should definitely use .sort_by, not .sort. No reason to use sort unless your behavior must have access to both elements in a pair, which isn't the case here...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My favorite approach to these kind of problems is to store an **extra** `sort_order` column in the database.

That way when you have 10000 songs that you would like to page through, you can do that in SQL and avoid having to pull them all back.

Its simple to add a `before_save` filter to keep this column in sync.

The cleanish solution, without schema changes is:

```
class Artist
  def sortable_name
    self.name.sub(/^(the|a|an)\s+/i, '')
  end
end

class Song
  def sortable_name
    # note the - is there so [Radio] [head on] and [Radiohead] [karma police] 
    #   are not mixed in the ordering
    "#{artist.sortable_name} - #{name}" 
  end
end

# breaks ties as well 
Song.all.sort_by { |song| song.sortable_name }
```

Comment: Storing an extra column lets you do some other nice things, like .downcase it, replace ä with ae and the like (if appropriate), reverse first/last names, etc., all without recomputing everything during every query...

Comment: you can also be more concise with symbol_to_proc but I personally dislike that trick ...

Comment: Looks good, though what do you mean by "in cases like 'the the'..."?

Comment: Bad example: I mean that if you do not have some sort of delimiter between the artist and song name you may confuse your ordering in some weird cases.

Comment: yerp Id imagine that would be fine

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off doing this in SQL,

```
SELECT Title,
CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1)
        IN ('a', 'an', 'the')
    THEN CONCAT(
        SUBSTRING(Title, INSTR(Title, ' ') + 1),
        ', ',
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(Title, ' ', 1)
    )
    ELSE Title
END AS TitleSort
FROM music
ORDER BY TitleSort
```

There is an [article](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/how-to-sort-mysql-results-ignoring-definite-and-indefinite-articles-the-a-an.html) describing this in more detail as well.

The big benefit over the approach you have laid out is that you're pulling ALL of the records out first which will screw you up in subtle ways both performance and user interface wise (I'm thinking of situations like trying to page through a large set of songs).

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be correct but probably u can change it to:

```
Song.all.sort {|x, y| x.artist.name.sub(/^(the|a|an)\s/i, '') <=> y.artist.name.sub(/^(the|a|an)\s/i, '') }
```

changed to sub because you only need to change it in the beginning and not the whole string, space changed to \s to indicate a space.

you can go to http://www.rubyxp.com/ to test your regex

if it's still not working then probably some records are not coming out the way they should? like spaces at the *start* of the string, nil or blank title, etc...

hope it helps =)

Answer (score 0):

Break it up!

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base

  def <=>(other)
    name.gsub(/^(the|a|an) /i, '') <=> other.name.gsub(/^(the|a|an) /i, '')
  end

end

songs = Song.all(:include => :artist)
songs.sort_by { |s| s.artist }
```

Comment: For some reason, code formatting is eating up full lines of code above. Please see pastie here: http://pastie.org/612206