# How to convert strings with (in)definate articles for AMA alphabetization in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know a better way to word this question, which is probably why I'm struggling with finding an answer.

I want to alphabetize a list of song titles using AMA alphabetization, where (in)definate articles are converted with the article placed at the end with a delineating comma. For example:

```
"The Way Forward" => "Way Forward, The"
"The Long and Winding Road" => "Long and Winding Road, The"
"A Late Night Alone" => "Late Night Alone, A"
```

I can write a method that does this for me if I have to, but there are useful methods like `Pluralize` and `Titleize` and `Humanize` that I'm wondering if a method for this already exists.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing. You can read a very similar question from 2009: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402915/sort-an-array-in-ruby-ignoring-articles-the-a-an

Comment: Nothing I can find in the std:lib and nothing in ActionView either. I came across https://github.com/rossmeissl/indefinite_article but this is for adding articles not identifying them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you for your comments [Maciej Nędza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9335023/maciej-n%C4%99dza) and [Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196834/ash). So it seems that the answer is no, there is no prebuilt method for reordering strings starting with "The", "A", or "An" in Ruby on Rails' libraries.

So in case someone finds this post looking for an answer, I'll post the code I'm using to solve this problem.

The model `Song` has the string `title` for the song title, and another column `sort_order` to hold the modified title for sorting alphabetically.

```
# app/models/song.rb
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_sort_order

....

  private
    def set_sort_order
      unless title.starts_with?("The ", "A ", "An ")
        self.sort_order = title
      else 
        word = title.partition(" ").first
        self.sort_order = title["#{word} ".size..-1].concat(", #{word}")
      end
    end
end
```